# Pandas - How to show pivot data values ​grouped by a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have attendance dataset with 4 columns (person_id, clock_in_time, clock_out_time, and date), it looks like this:

```
   person_id                 c_in                c_out        date
0          3  2023-07-01 07:10:10  2023-07-01 17:20:10  2023-07-01
1          3  2023-07-02 07:07:10  2023-07-02 17:09:10  2023-07-02
2          3  2023-07-03 07:05:10  2023-07-03 17:50:10  2023-07-03
3          3  2023-07-04 07:21:10  2023-07-04 17:06:10  2023-07-04
4          4  2023-07-01 07:02:10  2023-07-01 17:50:10  2023-07-01
5          4  2023-07-02 07:08:10  2023-07-02 17:17:10  2023-07-02
```

I want to pivot my data and group it by date and person id as the column, so i did this:

```
df_att_pivoted = df_att.pivot(index= 'date', columns='person_id', values=['c_in', 'c_out'])
```

the output look like this

Actual Output Image:

[image: Actual Output Image]

Actually, there is no problem in this result as a dataframe, but since I want to export this data to an excel format, it would be easier to read if it grouped by person id. So, is it possible to display the data by c_in and c_out for each person id?

My desired output would be:

Desired Output Image:

[image: Desired Output Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method1**

swaplevel and sort to df_att_pivot

```
df_att_pivoted.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
```

**Method2**

when make pivot table by df_att, use `groupby` and unstack

```
df_att.groupby(['person_id', 'date'])[['c_in', 'c_out']].sum().stack().unstack([0, 2])
```

---

**Common output of Method1 and Method2**

[image]